# Count the number of times single specific value appears in column

Tags: c#, sql

I'm writing an ASP.NET page. I'm trying to write a query to get the total of times a specific value exists within the column:

Table Courses:

```
CourseSubject
--------------
ECT
HCI
HCI
```

I only want to return the number of times that name2 appears.

I have this so far but keep getting an error:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT CourseSubject, COUNT(*) AS ETC FROM Courses;
```

Comment: You have to add `group by CourseSubject` as you are using an aggregate function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CourseSubject, COUNT(*) AS ETC FROM Courses
Group BY CourseSubject
```

This gives you the count of all courses in the table

If you only want one specific count you can do this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS ETC FROM Courses WHERE CourseSubject = 'Name2'
```

Comment: What if I just want to count name2 individuals instead of all the courses in the table?

Comment: why would you not use `count(1) where ..` which returns a single number instead of returning a bunch of 1's ?

Comment: @BrokenGlass. Sorry I misunderstood your comment. Updated the answer